# How to run Python interactive window with the -m flag in VSCode?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

### Explanation

VS code has this functionality named .py interactive window, which basically is jupyter notebook cells inside a .py file.

This makes my work much more efficient and easier because I cant **test** my modules like in Jupyter Notebook, **use it as a module** like .py files and also **invoke it as script using python myscript.py**. More detailed description here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

---

#### Problem

Right now if i want this setup to work I have to make imports by using:

```
sys.path.append("path/to/my/module.py")
```

Is there a way I can run my modules in interactive window with the -m flag so it doesn't fail when doing relative imports?

If not, is there another standardised way that also enables me running the script using VS Code jupyter cells inside .py files without having to import packages using `sys.path.append`

---

#### What I have tried

Until now I have tried adding ` __init__.py ` file to each subfolder but it still doesn't work, it fails when using relative imports from interactive window.

---

Any help, is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the problem, something that I do with notebooks is use pyprojroot and at the top I usually have `os.chdir(pyprojroot.here())`, to ensure that I'm running the notebook from the project root.

Comment: The best solution is to use virtual environment and a package manager such as `poetry` that makes everything easier by installing the current project and then no `sys.path.append` is needed anymore